# Calculadora com as 4 operações básicas e crie um local para o usuário escrever suas informações e exibir no alert após o resultado

Tags: javascript, html

Olá, é meu primeiro post nesse site e gostaria de uma ajuda, preciso criar uma calculadora que o usuário possa colocar o nome para que quando o alert exibisse o resultado, aparecesse o nome, por exemplo: ''**Olá, Marcos, o resultado da soma é: X''**

o codigo está abaixo, preciso só a modificação pra criar a caixa para escrever o nome e a modificação no alert.

desde ja obrigado.

```
<html>
<header>
<title>Calculadora</title>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   function somarValores(){
   var n1 = document.getElementById("s1").value;
   var n2 = document.getElementById("s2").value;
   var n3 = parseInt(n1) + parseInt(n2);
   alert(n3);
    }
function multiplicarValores(){
  var n1 = document.getElementById("s1").value;
   var n2 = document.getElementById("s2").value;
   var n3 = parseInt(n1) * parseInt(n2);
   alert(n3);
}   
function dividirValores(){
   var n1 = document.getElementById("s1").value;
   var n2 = document.getElementById("s2").value;
   var n3 = parseInt(n1) / parseInt(n2);
   alert(n3);
}   
function subtrairValores(){
   var n1 = document.getElementById("s1").value;
   var n2 = document.getElementById("s2").value;
   var n3 = parseInt(n1) - parseInt(n2);
   alert(n3);
}   
</script>
</header> 
 <body>
   Hello world
    <legend>somas</legend>
<label>Valor 1:</label>
<input id="s1" type="text"/>
<label>Valor 2:</label>
<input id="s2" type="text"/>
<button id="somar" onclick="somarValores()">Somar</button>
<button id="multiplicar" onclick="multiplicarValores()">multiplicar</button>
<button id="dividir" onclick="dividirValores()">dividir</button>
<button id="subtrair" onclick="subtrairValores()">subtrair</button>
   </body>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basta colocar outro input e concatenar os valores:

```
<html>
<header>
<title>Calculadora</title>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   function somarValores(){
   var n1 = document.getElementById("s1").value;
   var n2 = document.getElementById("s2").value;
   var n3 = parseInt(n1) + parseInt(n2);
   var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
   alert("Olá " + name + ', o resultado é: ' +n3);
    }
function multiplicarValores(){
  var n1 = document.getElementById("s1").value;
   var n2 = document.getElementById("s2").value;
   var n3 = parseInt(n1) * parseInt(n2);
   var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
   alert("Olá " + name + ', o resultado é: ' +n3);
}   
function dividirValores(){
   var n1 = document.getElementById("s1").value;
   var n2 = document.getElementById("s2").value;
   var n3 = parseInt(n1) / parseInt(n2);
   var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
   alert("Olá " + name + ', o resultado é: ' +n3);
}   
function subtrairValores(){
   var n1 = document.getElementById("s1").value;
   var n2 = document.getElementById("s2").value;
   var n3 = parseInt(n1) - parseInt(n2);
   var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
   alert("Olá " + name + ', o resultado é: ' +n3);
}   
</script>
</header> 
 <body>
   Hello world
    <legend>somas</legend>
    <label>Nome:</label>
<input id="name" type="text"/>
<label>Valor 1:</label>
<input id="s1" type="text"/>
<label>Valor 2:</label>
<input id="s2" type="text"/>
<button id="somar" onclick="somarValores()">Somar</button>
<button id="multiplicar" onclick="multiplicarValores()">multiplicar</button>
<button id="dividir" onclick="dividirValores()">dividir</button>
<button id="subtrair" onclick="subtrairValores()">subtrair</button>
   </body>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!